# Is the Rails CookieStore tamper proof by default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The [ActionController Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session) says:

> The cookie data is cryptographically signed to make it tamper-proof,
>   but it is not encrypted, so anyone with access to it can read its
>   contents but not edit it (Rails will not accept it if it has been
>   edited).

[These docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html) say that `cookies.signed[:user_id] = current_user.id`...

> [sets] a signed cookie, which prevents a user from tampering with its
>   value. The cookie is signed by your app's config.secret_token
>   value. Rails generates this value by default when you create a new
>   Rails app.

The first quote makes it seem as if cookie data is generally tamper-proof, while the second states that unless you add `.signed`, the data can be tampered. Which is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs are talking about two different things.

1. If you use a session cookie, it will be signed. (In Rails 4, you have an option to encrypt and sign.)
2. Other cookies may be signed if you call `signed`.